# how to update wireless-regdb in Ubuntu12.04?

Tags: wireless

my wifiAC NIC card is running in 40MHz channel (expect 80/160 MHz) , I need to update my wireless-regdb in my Ubuntu 12.04, anybody did this? and how? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used "iw reg get" and it returns country US:
        (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
        (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
        (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
        (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
        (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
        (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
        (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40). I want to use 80/160 MHz channel for my wifiAC NIC card. So the question is how to change it from 40 to 80 MHz channel?

Comment: Figured it out by myself later, would like to post here so others may need it. 1. download tar ball "wireless-regdb-2013.11.27.tar.xz" 2. unpack it and find the file "db.txt" 3.overwrite the one in driver path "/net/wireless" 4. turn on compile flag "CONFIG_CFG80211_INTERNAL_REGDB" and rebuild kernel.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to set your regulatory domain explicitly, then check yours from the terminal:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0, add the line:

```
iw reg set IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out later by myself, would like to post here so others may need it. 1. download tar ball "wireless-regdb-2013.11.27.tar.xz" 2. unpack it and find the file "db.txt" 3.overwrite the one in driver path "/net/wireless" 4. turn on compile flag "CONFIG_CFG80211_INTERNAL_REGDB" and rebuild kernel.